# unable to add SSH Key on Remote Server with Ansible

Tags: ssh, yaml, ansible

I'm working with `Ansible` and trying to put `SSH Key` from my Server to another Remote Server.

Here is my code.

```
- name: Add RSA key to the remote host 
  authorized_key:
    user:
      name:"{{ item.user }}"
    key:"{{ lookup('file', '/home/ansible/.ssh/id_rsa.pub') }}"
    path:"/home/{{ item.username }}/.ssh/authorized_keys"
  when: item.get('state', 'present') == 'present'
  with_items: USER_LIST
```

and getting the following error every time when I try to execute it.

```
ERROR: Syntax Error while loading YAML script, /home/ansible/public_html/ansible/roles/user/tasks/main.yml
```

Note: The error may actually appear before this position: line 39, column 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong, try this:

```
- name: Add RSA key to the remote host 
  authorized_key:
    user: "{{ item.user }}"
    key: "{{ lookup('file', '/home/ansible/.ssh/id_rsa.pub') }}"
    path: "/home/{{ item.username }}/.ssh/authorized_keys"
  when: item.get('state', 'present') == 'present'
  with_items: USER_LIST
```